# Concatenating string from columns that include nulls with case statement in TSQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, concatenation, case

I am trying to create a string, to insert into a column in a new table, that is constructed from multiple columns from another table.

As an example:

```
Source table 
    Value_1 : '10'
    Value_2 : '30'
    Value_3 : '120';

Destination table
    Column A : '10,30,120,';
```

So my code is as follows:

```
INSERT INTO DESTINATION TABLE
    Value_1 + ',' +
    Value_2 + ','+
    Value_3 +',';
```

This works well. My problem is that if one of the columns in the source table is equal to NULL, then my concatenated string result is NULL.

```
Source table
    Value_1 : '10'
    Value_2 : NULL
    Value_3 : '120'
```

Results in

```
Destination table
    Column A : NULL
```

If one of the values in the source table is NULL, I would like that part of the string to just have '0' as a value.

In other words, my desired output is:

```
Column A : '10,0,120,';
```

Could someone show me the syntax to achieve this?

If it's relevant, I'm using MSSQL server 2014.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is `NULL` + `Anything`  = `NULL`, Use `ISNULL` or `COALESCE` function to replace `0` When values is `NULL`

```
isnull(Value_1,0) + ',' +
isnull(Value_2,0) + ','+
isnull(Value_3,0) +','
```